# Converting this code to Rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to convert the following code to run on Ruby 2.2.2 and Rails 4.2.4. I can't get the image to lock and stay with the text. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code?

Here is the code:

```
<div id="portfolio">
  <!-- Add the above used filter names inside div tag. You can add more     than one filter names. For image lightbox you need to include "a" tag pointing to image link, along with the class "prettyphoto". -->
  <div class="element one three"><a href="img/portfolio/1.jpg" class="prettyphoto">
    <img src="img/portfolio/1.jpg" alt="" />
    <!-- Portfolio caption -->
    <div class="pcap bred">
      <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor</h4>
      <p>Sed justo dui, scelerisque ut vel, eleifend id erat.</p>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="element two one"><a href="img/portfolio/2.jpg" class="prettyphoto">
  <img src="img/portfolio/2.jpg" alt="" />
  <div class="pcap borange">
    <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor</h4>
    <p>Sed justo dui, scelerisque ut vel, eleifend id erat.</p>
  </div>
</a>
</div>
<div class="element three five"><a href="img/portfolio/3.jpg" class="prettyphoto">
  <img src="img/portfolio/3.jpg" alt="" />
  <div class="pcap blightblue">
    <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor</h4>
    <p>Sed justo dui, scelerisque ut vel, eleifend id erat.</p>
  </div>
</a>
</div>
```

It is supposed to look like this:

[image]

My code looks like this but the image is split off from the text:

```
<div id="portfolio">
  <!-- Add the above used filter names inside div tag. You can add more than one filter names. For image lightbox you need to include "a" tag pointing to image link, along with the class "prettyphoto". -->
  <div class="element one three">
    <a><%= image_tag("portfolio/1.jpg", class: "prettyphoto") %>
      <!-- Portfolio caption -->
      <div class="pcap bred">
        <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor</h4>
        <p>Sed justo dui, scelerisque ut vel, eleifend id erat.</p>
      </div>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="element two one">
  <%= image_tag("portfolio/2.jpg", class: "prettyphoto") %>
  <div class="pcap borange">
    <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor</h4>
    <p>Sed justo dui, scelerisque ut vel, eleifend id erat.</p>
  </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: So what's with the misplaced closing anchor tags?

Comment: Perhaps the best name for that question would be something like: "Problem converting HTML to Rails`.

Answer (score 2):

You have some problems when closing divs and it's better use `link_to`. Try this:

```
<div id="portfolio">
  <!-- Add the above used filter names inside div tag. You can add more than one filter names. For image lightbox you need to include "a" tag pointing to image link, along with the class "prettyphoto". -->
  <div class="element one three">
    <%= link_to "#" do %>
      <%= image_tag("portfolio/1.jpg", class: "prettyphoto") %>
      <!-- Portfolio caption -->
      <div class="pcap bred">
        <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor</h4>
        <p>Sed justo dui, scelerisque ut vel, eleifend id erat.</p>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  <div class="element two one">
    <%= link_to "#" do %>
      <%= image_tag("portfolio/2.jpg", class: "prettyphoto") %>
      <div class="pcap borange">
        <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor</h4>
        <p>Sed justo dui, scelerisque ut vel, eleifend id erat.</p>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```